# Effective Cartier Divisor gives Regular Global Section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $D \subset X$ an effective cartier divisor which arises from the invertible ideal sheaf $ \gamma = \mathcal{O}_X (-D)$ by considering the exact sequence

$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_X (-D) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_D \to 0 $

Tensoring by $ \mathcal{O}_X (D) $ gives

$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_X  \xrightarrow{\text{s}} \mathcal{O}_X (D) \to \mathcal{O}_D (D) \to 0 $

with $ \mathcal{O}_D (D)= \mathcal{O}_D \otimes \mathcal{O}_X (D)$ and the left arrow comes from global section $s \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X (D))$.

My question is why this global section $s$ in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01X0 is called REGULAR global section?

The definition of a regular element of a ring $R$ is the following:

$r' \in R$ regular $ \Leftrightarrow$ $r':R \to R, r \to r* r'$ is injective.

But here I get only the injectivity by multiplying $s$ with elements from $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, but in general not with all elements from $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_D (D))$.

So why $s$ is then regular?

Comment: Regular is used in algebraic geometry to mean without poles, so after an (admittedly brief) glance, it appears that it's being used here for emphasis, to distinguish from a rational section.

Comment: To be more clear, one says a rational function is regular on an open set if it has no poles on that set.

Comment: The subsheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is defined as the sheaf of meromorphic functions $\mathcal{K}_X$ on $X$ as follows:
${\mathcal{O}_X(D)}_{\mid U_i}=\mathcal{O}_{ U_i}\frac{1}{f_i}$ for a covering $\{U_i\}_i$.

Now the section $s$ induced by $\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(D)$ 
is the same as global invertible meromorphic function $f$ on $X$. For every $i\in I$ we have:

$s_{\mid U_i}=\frac{s_i}{f_i}$ for some $s_i\in \mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$. So according to your argument all every $s_i$ shouldn't have poles, right?

Comment: It's clear in the context that if $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ is a ring of polynomial rationals but in the general context that $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ is an abstract ring, what do you mean by "$s_i$ don't have poles"?

Comment: In the abstract case, saying that the $s_i$ don't have poles on $U_i$ is just saying that $s_i \in \mathcal O_X(U_i)$ (but the containment does not hold on larger open sets containing the locus of poles).